# Replace with multiple strings in multiple lines of a file

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop

I have a file containing six lines as below:

```
 a1
 b1
 c1
 d1
 e1
 f1
```

The requirement is  that, the output needs to be as below. Simply put, the lower case letters in the above lines, need to be replaced with "AA" and "AB", thrice each.

```
AA1
AA1
AA1
AB1
AB1
AB1
```

I have been using the below code to achieve this:

```
For each line in File.ReadLines(path)
    For i as integer = 1 to 3
        fOut.WriteLine(Regex.replace(line, regex, replacementString(matchCount)))
    Next
Next
```

The function replacementString(matchCount) returns either "AA" or "AB" depending on the paramter passed.
I have used the "for" loop to iterate over the replacement String(AA or AB) thrice. But, along with the replacement Strings, the line is also getting looped thrice, and is being written thrice into the file. Instead of getting six lines as output, I get 18 lines as output.

I can't wrap my head around as to how I can make the inner for-loop execute only for the replacementString() and not for the line. I am new to programming and would like to know if there is a way to achieve this.

The above code is just to give an example as to what my problem is. In the actual situation, I face this problem for hundreds of lines in a file, which need to be replaced by AA.....ZZ. I can't post my original code from work.

Comment: `matchCount` doesn't seem to be changing at all in your code..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot intertwine two `For` loops that way. The simplest way to structure something like this is by looping "manually" for the sort-of-inner loop:

```
Dim i as Integer = 0
For Each line in File.ReadLines(path)
    fOut.WriteLine(Regex.replace(line, regex, replacementString(i + 1)))
    i = (i + 1) Mod 3
Next
```

Note: I am assuming that `matchCount` and `i` are actually the same variable in your real code. I don't see how your code makes sense otherwise.